# NSNumberFormatter keep decimal separator even when no decimals are present

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel, decimal, nsformatter

I have a UILabel and its formatter :

```
 NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@"."];
[formatter setGroupingSize:3];
[formatter setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:NO];
[formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
[formatter setDecimalSeparator:@","];

NSString *formattedString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:12.]]];
```

**So that my formattedString is returning 12**

**What If I want to keep the comma when there is no decimal? So that my UIlabel prints out "12."?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see comma when there is no decimal, set `alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator` accordingly

```
[formatter setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:YES];
```

Thus, your `UILabel` will say "12," (not "12.").